# What causes the removal of my cookie upon refreshing the page?

Tags: node.js, session, next.js, cookies

I'm encountering an issue with cookie management in my web application built using Next.js 13 for the frontend and Node.js for the backend. Despite successfully setting the cookies on the server side, Chrome unexpectedly clears the cookies upon page refresh.

```
  res.cookie('accessToken', accessTokenJWT, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true, //process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    signed: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + oneDay),
  });

  res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshTokenJWT, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true, //process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    signed: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + longerExp),
  });
};
```

Steps Taken:

- Using Node.js, I'm setting cookies for **`accessToken`** and **`refreshToken`** with specific attributes including **`Path`**, **`Expires`**, **`HttpOnly`**, and **`Secure`**.
- Provided response headers indicate successful transmission of cookies as part of the HTTP response.

#### The Problem:

However, upon page refresh, Chrome seems to be clearing these cookies, disrupting the intended user authentication flow.

Relevant Details:

- Browser: Google Chrome
- Server Configuration: Node.js
- Frameworks: Next.js 13 for frontend
- Request and response headers are in the provided structured format below.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK:
  Content-Length: 29
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Date: Tue, 31 Oct 2023 20:42:42 GMT
  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
  ETag: W/"1d-SUDaWU/q2dcldXFBDZxiPXz37Fo"
  Set-Cookie:
    - accessToken: s%3AeyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7Im5hbWUiOiJBQkRJUklTQUsgWVVTVUYiLCJ1c2VySWQiOiI2NTM3YWMyZWUyODk2YTZiY2QzNmU4NGYiLCJyb2xlIjoiQURNSU4ifSwiaWF0IjoxNjk4Nzg0OTYyfQ.JsomTCXDe-xOo3UWUQbNjKm9DwMdmN4daVX_odrQDaY.t3m5OrryAfVzyKBpj9fapRNx2UsSGfTDcKjrDEDKbkM
      Path: /
      Expires: Wed, 01 Nov 2023 20:42:42 GMT
      HttpOnly: true
      Secure: true
    - refreshToken: s%3AeyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7Im5hbWUiOiJBQkRJUklTQUsgWVVTVUYiLCJ1c2VySWQiOiI2NTM3YWMyZWUyODk2YTZiY2QzNmU4NGYiLCJyb2xlIjoiQURNSU4ifSwicmVmcmVzaFRva2VuIjoiYTU4Y2U2Mzg3MmEwMTczNTllYWE2NzZhYTU2YTA5YzY0OTk1ODg3ZDdlMWIyY2FhZWU4M2RhNWExOWY4ZTk1Zjc3OTZhZjY4YWQwYTdhNzMiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTg3ODQ5NjJ9.XFAkKg37u2EnajwioD9M5otqsp9ovONxxOmgWyZYlk0.08FU6sNeJCvOZZxUqjU679PJ2Fh6cNe8hOBnZA4qWCA
      Max-Age: 1701376962
      Path: /
      Expires: Wed, 29 Sep 2077 17:25:24 GMT
      Secure: true
  Vary: Origin
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
  X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
  X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
  X-RateLimit-Reset: 1698785283
  Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
  Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-origin
  Origin-Agent-Cluster: ?1
  Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
  X-Download-Options: noopen
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
  X-XSS-Protection: 0
  Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https://jam.dev blob: i.imgur.com data:; base-uri 'self'; font-src 'self' https: data:; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https://jam.dev blob: i.imgur.com; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' https://jam.dev blob: i.imgur.com data:; script-src-attr 'none'; style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline'; upgrade-insecure-requests
  Timing-Allow-Origin: *
```

Any insights, suggestions, or solutions to debug and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**What I Tried:**

1. **Cookie Configuration:** Configured cookies for `accessToken` and `refreshToken` on the server-side using Node.js.

2. **Specified Attributes:** Set attributes such as `Path`, `Expires`, `HttpOnly`, and `Secure` for the cookies.

3. **Verified Headers:** Examined the provided response headers to ensure cookies were correctly transmitted.

**Expected Outcome:**

- Expected cookies to persist and remain stored in the browser even after a page refresh.

- Anticipated the `accessToken` and `refreshToken` cookies to facilitate user authentication seamlessly across sessions.

**Actual Result**:

- Despite successful transmission from the server, Chrome unexpectedly clears the cookies upon page refresh.

- The intended behavior of persistent cookies maintaining user sessions is disrupted due to this unexpected clearance.